# How can i use handleScroll in my current component?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I want to set the handleScroll event for my component, but the current code I have is triggered when I move the scroll of the browser window, I want it to be triggered when I move the scroll of my component, what should I do?

```
import classNames from 'classnames'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Header = _ => {
  const [ scrolled, setScrolled ] = useState()
  const classes = classNames('header', {
    scrolled: scrolled,
  })
  useEffect(_ => {
    const handleScroll = _ => { 
      console.log(11111)
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    return _ => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <TableBody>
            {lis.map((l, i) => (
              <Rows
                key={i}
              />
            ))}
          </TableBody>
  )
}
export default Header
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the scroll listener event on the window instead of the component.

You can use React's [`onScroll`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#ui-events) event instead of attaching `addEventListener` to your Header element manually.

```
...
const handleScroll = _ => { 
    console.log(11111)
}

return (
    <div onScroll={handleScroll}>
        <TableBody>
            {lis.map((l, i) => (
              <Rows
                key={i}
              />
            ))}
          </TableBody>
    </div>
);
...
```

Make sure that your component is scrollable.

Comment: i am getting this error <tbody> cannot appear as a child of <div>. and  <div> cannot appear as a child of <table>.

Comment: That makes sense. You can add the `onScroll` event to the `TableBody` as a prop and make sure `TableBody` passes it to the element it is rendering.